# How to disable EditText control during activity load and enable it by user action

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, disabled-control

I have an activity that loads that has multiple EditText controls and a button.  The EditText controls display values from a SQLlite DB.  I want the EditTtext controls to be read-only (not clickable even) when the activity loads and then to become editable/clickable when the user clicks a button.

I've read a bunch of the other threads here and it seems like you can do this a couple different ways.

1. Disable control in XML and enable in code (user action)
2. Disable the control in code (onCreate) and enable in code (user action)

Right now I can't get either way to work.  It seems like if I disable it, I can never enable it again for user input.  And if I enable it, It's always enabled and I can never disable it.

Here is my current code:

XML - This is the control I want disabled until the user does something (clicks button)

```
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.5"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:cursorVisible="true"
            android:editable="false"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:id="@+id/itemPrice"/>
    </TableRow>
    <!-- End Item Price -->
```

JAVA - This is the code that just clears the form/UI and attempts to enable the 2 EditText fields for user input

```
//Add item to the inventory.  Enables the EditText control for user intput (name and price)
public void addNewItem(View view)
{
    try
    {
        //Clear the fields on the form/UI
        itemId.setText("");
        itemName.setText("");
        itemPrice.setText("");
        itemDelete.setText("");

        //Enable the controls
        itemName.setEnabled(true);
        itemPrice.setEnabled(true);
        itemName.setFocusable(true);
        itemPrice.setFocusable(true);
        itemName.setClickable(true);
        itemPrice.setClickable(true);
    }
    catch(Exception erMsg)
    {
        erMsg.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I still have setEnabled(true) on each control even though it has never been disabled, but the latest code is just attempting anything to enable it.

I don't want to make this question subjective, but is there a better way if there is priority (XML or Java)?  For instance, if XML sets a field to :focusable:false and Java sets the field setFocusable(true), is there priority?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll put the answer here as it seems this question is asked a lot and the answers are never really understood or clear.

This is the way that I did it without using XML

In the onCreate() method, I disabled user input by the following code:

```
//Disable the itemName control
        itemName.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
        itemName.setFocusable(false);

        //Disable the itemPrice control
        itemPrice.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
        itemPrice.setFocusable(false);
```

I enabled the controls after the user clicked a button, but it wasn't done in the actionListener for the button, just a method that is called when the button is clicked.

```
//Enable the controls
            itemName.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
            itemName.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            itemName.setFocusable(true);

        itemPrice.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
        itemPrice.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        itemPrice.setFocusable(true);
```

This fully works and when the EditText is not enabled for editing, it is still visible (not greyed out when setDisabled(true)

Answer (score 0):

you may set the `android:editable` dynamically, after the loading is completed, as   `android:editable ="true"`

Comment: I'm confused on your answer.  I have set the 2 fields to editable=false in the XML (when it loads) and now I want the 2 fields to be editable.  There is no method "Editable" for EditText controls.  How are you suggesting to enable it dynamically?  Please put the XML/Code